# how to use WHERE clause and WITH in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a small project using `laravel` and i would like to know how can i use `WHERE` clause for `apartment` this is my `code`

```
$buildings = Building::with('apartment')->get();
```

i have already tried :

```
$buildings = Building::with('apartment')->where('name','=',5)->get();
```

but it applies for Building not for apartment.

how can i apply WHERE clause for apartment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a Closure to `with(...)` if you pass in an array using the following syntax:

```php
Model::with(['relation_name' => function ($query) { ... }])
```

In your case, what you're looking for is:

```
$buildings = Building::with(['apartment' => function ($apartments) {
    $apartments->where('name', 5); // if you don't pass an operator, it's assumed to be '='.
}])->get();
```

You can also write it like this using PHP 7.4 shorthand closures.

```
$buildings = Building::with(['apartment' => fn($apartments) => $apartments->where('name', 5)])->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $buildings = App\Building::with(['apartment' => function ($query) {
   $query->where('name', 5); .
   }])->get();
```